# Mapping unit sphere to ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an $N$-dimensional space. Let $M$ be a square $N\times N$ (real, but I am interested in complex case too) matrix.

Are the following (hyper)ellipsoids (or degenerate hyperellipsoids)?

1. $\{v \,:\, \lvert Mv\rvert=1\}$,
2. $\{v \,:\, v^TMv=1\}$,
3. $\{\lvert Mv\rvert \,:\, \lvert v\rvert=1 \}$,
4. $\{v^TMv \,:\, \lvert v\rvert=1 \}$.

Can every ellipsoid centered at the start of coordinates be represented in the above forms (for some matrix $M$)?

If they define ellipsoids, which of the forms is better to describe a mapping of the unit sphere to an ellipsoid (or maybe ellipsoid to the unit sphere, I'm not sure)? The second form look like less computational intensive, as not need to calculate the module of a vector (and thus square root).

The task we attempt to solve is to linearly map the unit sphere into an arbitrary hyperlellipsoid (or maybe back).

Comment: Oh, I've realized that $v\mapsto v^T M v$ is not a linear map and so it probably not appropriate for us. Well, it may be interesting anyway (despite of no linearity)